# Google client library through Composer not installing

Tags: php, composer-php, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to install Google client library with composer using:

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC
```

and I get this

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - Conclusion: don't install google/apiclient 2.x-dev
        - Conclusion: don't install google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC6
        - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC4 requires google/auth 0.5 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.5].
        - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC5 requires google/auth 0.5 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.5].
        - Conclusion: don't install google/auth v0.5
        - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle == 4.2.3.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.3].
        - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.2.* -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.2.0].
        - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC2 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.2.* -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.2.0].
        - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC3 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.2.* -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.2.0].
        - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.2.0
        - Installation request for google/apiclient ~2.0@dev -> satisfiable by google/apiclient[2.x-dev, v2.0.0-RC1, v2.0.0-RC2, v2.0.0-RC3, v2.0.0-RC4, v2.0.0-RC5, v2.0.0-RC6].
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

- `composer require google/apiclient:2.0.0-RC6`

  - fetching version by tag name `2.0.0-RC6`
- `composer require google/apiclient:2.0.*@dev`

  - version from `2.0.*` range with `dev` stability

---

Example run for `composer require google/apiclient:2.0.*@dev`:

```
./composer.json has been created
Warning: You should avoid overwriting already defined auth settings for github.com.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.2.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.1.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.1.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpseclib/phpseclib (2.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.18.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing firebase/php-jwt (v3.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing google/auth (v0.7)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing google/apiclient (v2.0.0-RC6)
    Loading from cache

phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-libsodium (SSH2/SFTP can make use of some algorithms provided by the libsodium-php extension.)
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-gmp (Install the GMP (GNU Multiple Precision) extension in order to speed up arbitrary precision integer arithmetic operations.)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing raven/raven (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing videlalvaro/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server via PHP Driver)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: Both just give the same kind of problems.

Comment: Both commands work for me. Log attached. - You probably have other clashing dependencies defined in your require section.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue with another Google package when running `composer update`:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - googleads/googleads-php-lib dev-experimental requires google/auth 0.7 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.7].
    - googleads/googleads-php-lib dev-experimental requires google/auth 0.7 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.7].
    - Conclusion: don't install google/auth v0.7
    - Installation request for googleads/googleads-php-lib dev-experimental -> satisfiable by googleads/googleads-php-lib[dev-experimental].
```

I had no conflicting packages. The solution was to:

- Temporarily remove the `googleads/googleads-php-lib` line from composer.json
- Run `composer update`
- Reintroduce the line in composer.json
- Run `composer update` again

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this same problem while developing an application that needed Google Library. There is a package you have installed that required another version of the Google Library dependency package, in my case it was `firebase/php-jwt (v4.0.0)` whereas the Google Library required **v3.0.0**.